# How to use cgroup v2 to limit memory and cpu per user group?

Tags: linux, cgroup, rocky-linux

With cgroup v1, I can have group configuration in cgconfig.conf and assign groups to different users in cgrules.conf

However, it seems to me that cgconfig and cgrules can't be used along with cgroup v2. The only way I know to use cgroup v2 is to apply a group to running processes.

Is there anything similar like cgconfig and cgred for cgroup v2?

What needs to be done to limit memory usage per user (or a group of users) using cgroup v2?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything similar like cgconfig and cgred for cgroup v2?

Cgred is a part of libcgroup. General support for cgroup v2 was added in libcgroup v2.0.

**Cgconfigparser and cgred works with cgroup v2** at least since libcgroup v3.0.0 (didn't used older ones).
BTW, only cgroup v2 hierarchy was mounted in my case.